# How set UIPickerView in cascade

Tags: ios, view, uipickerview, picker

I'm trying to set two `UIPickerView`s, both are filled with `NSDictionary`, this work ok, but I need to the second `UIPickerView` implement a refresh depends of the selection of the first `UIPickerView`, understand me?

The first `UIPickerView` is filled this way:

```
for (NSDictionary *local in json) {
    NSString *nombre = [local objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *idLocal = [local objectForKey:@"id"];

    self.dicLocales = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: idLocal, @"idLocal", nombre, @"nombreLocal", nil];
    [listaLocales addObject:self.dicLocales];
}
```

And the second `UIPickerView` is filled this way:

```
for (NSDictionary *servicio in json) {
    NSString *nombre = [servicio objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *idServicio = [servicio objectForKey:@"id"];

    self.dicServicios = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: idServicio, @"idServicio", nombre, @"nombreServicio", idLocal, @"idLocal", nil];
    [listaServicios1 addObject:self.dicServicios];
}
```

You note  variable `idLocal`, that corresponds to id of the first `UIPickerView` rows. Then, I need, if in the first `UIPickerView` is selected row with idLocal 1, in the second `UIPickerView` is reloaded or refreshing only with rows corresponds to idLocal 1.

Please hope somebody can help me, and sorry for my English :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to implement `<UIPickerViewDelegate>` Method as below

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if ([pickerView isEqual:FirstPickerView]) {
        //SecondPickerView fill code
        [SecondPickerView reloadAllComponents];
    }
    else {
        //SecondPickerView Selected row
    }
}
```

and change your second UIPickerView **fill Loop** accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using (NSInteger)component   0 is the first row and so on.

```
if (component == 0) {
    if (row == 0) {

    }
    else if (row == 1)
    {

    }
}
else if (component == 1)
{
    selectedPositionIndex = row;
    if (row == 0) {

    }
    else if (row == 1)
    {

    }
    else if (row == 2)
    {

    }
    else if (row == 3)
    {

    }
}
```

This code works for just about all the picker view methods that provide the component NSInteger.

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

You will need to make sure you return the right item count for each component

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (component == 0) {
    return wordArray.count;
}
else if (component == 1)
{
    return positionArray.count;
}
return 0;
}
```